# How to display AD group name next to AD user with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, membership

I am a new PowerShell user and am trying to figure out how to get a list of users from a group with the group name displayed.

Desired output:

```
Username      AD Group       Department
john          SG-MSOffice    IT
jane          SG-MSOffice    Accounting
sam           SG-MSOffice    Accounting
thomas        SG-MSOffice    IT
```

Current output:

Code:

```
 Get-ADGroupMember -identity SG-MSOffice | Get-ADObject -Properties   name,department,manager
```

Output:

```
Department
DistinguishedName
manager
Name
ObjectClass
ObjectGUID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the group name somewhere and use `Select-Object` to format the output you want, like:

```
$groupname = "SG-MSOffice"
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname | Select-Object -Property @{n="Username";e={$_.Name}}, @{n="AD Group";e={$groupname}}, Department
```

I can't remember if `Department` is available in the "default"-object, if not, you could include something like `Get-ADObject`:

```
$groupname = "SG-MSOffice"
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname |
Get-ADObject -Properties Name, Department |
Select-Object -Property @{n="Username";e={$_.Name}}, @{n="AD Group";e={$groupname}}, Department
```

Comment: The first part of code returns this error message: Select-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Properties'.
At line:3 char:56
+ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname | Select-Object -Properties @{n="Username ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: Fixed. Typo, as I copied it from your `Get-AdObject` line.